# Update prevState of a value inside an array of objects of the respective item in React using Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The below is the data I have, now I want to change its value whenever a counter's button is clicked, either increment or decrement.

```
 const [data,setData] = useState([
    { id: 1, value: 0 },
    { id: 2, value: 0},
    { id: 3, value: 0 },
    { id: 4, value: 0}
  ]);
```

This is my App component:

```
function App() {

  const [data,setData] = useState([
    { id: 1, value: 0 },
    { id: 2, value: 0},
    { id: 3, value: 0 },
    { id: 4, value: 0}
  ]);

  const handleDecrement = (amount) => {
    // setData([...data[e.target.id], value: prev => prev - amount ])
    // setData([...data, { value: prev => prev + amount}])

    // {data.map(user => (
    //         setData([...data].map(object => {
    //           if(object.id === user.id) {
    //             return {
    //               ...object,
    //               value: prev => prev - amount,
    //             }
    //           }
    //           else return object;
    //         }))
    // ))}

    {data.map(user =>
       (

            setData([...data].map(object => {
              if(object.id === user.id) {
                return {
                  ...object,
                  value: amount,
                }
              }
              else return object;
            }))

      )

    )
    }
  }

  const handleIncrement = (amount) => {
    // setData([...data, {...data, value: prevState => prevState + amount}]) not working

  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data.map(counter => (
          <Counter
              key={counter.id}
              index={counter.id}
              value={counter.value}
              onIncrement={handleIncrement}
              onDecrement={handleDecrement}
          />
      ))}


    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

As you can see above I tried many different approaches but none of them is working properly.

Here is my Counter Component:

```
function Counter(props) {


const value = props.value


    return (
        <div className="counter">
            <b>{value}</b>
            <div className="counter-controls">
                <button onClick={() => props.onDecrement(2)} className="button is-danger is-small">-</button>
                <button onClick={() => props.onIncrement(2)} className="button is-success is-small">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );

}

export default Counter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hopefully clarify your question here's what I think you're looking for:

- A counter has a reference to a user through an "id"
- Clicking "+" on a counter should increment the App's value for that ID by 2
- Clicking "-" on a counter should decrement the App's value for that ID by 2
- You are having difficulty connecting the "id" to the event

Assuming that's all correct here's the solution I've crafted:

```
import React, { useReducer } from "react";

function Counter({ value, onChange }) {
  return (
    <div className="counter">
      <b>{value}</b>
      <div className="counter-controls">
        <button
          onClick={() => onChange(-2)}
          className="button is-danger is-small"
        >
          -
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => onChange(2)}
          className="button is-success is-small"
        >
          +
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

// delta means change
const userScoreReducer = (state, { id, delta }) => {
  return state.map((userScore) => {
    if (userScore.id === id) {
      return {
        ...userScore,
        value: userScore.value + delta
      };
    } else {
      return userScore;
    }
  });
};

export default function App() {
  // using userScores as a more clear name for "data"
  const [userScores, handleChangeUserScore] = useReducer(userScoreReducer, [
    { id: 1, value: 0 },
    { id: 2, value: 0 },
    { id: 3, value: 0 },
    { id: 4, value: 0 }
  ]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {userScores.map(({ id, value }) => {
        return (
          <Counter
            key={id}
            value={value}
            onChange={(delta) => handleChangeUserScore({ id, delta })}
          />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

See it in action on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/counter-solution-e49vx?file=/src/App.js:0-1340).

> Note: I've replaced `useState` with `useReducer` since it allows us to create "actions" that work well when dealing with more complex data.

This solution passes in the id with the `onChange` function. You could also pass the `id` to the `Counter` for it to pass back up through `onChange`.

EDIT: using `useState`, you get:

```js
const [userScores, setUserScores] = useState([
    { id: 1, value: 0 },
    { id: 2, value: 0 },
    { id: 3, value: 0 },
    { id: 4, value: 0 }
  ]);

  const handleChangeUserScore = ({ id, delta }) => {
    setUserScores((prev) =>
      prev.map((userScore) => {
        if (userScore.id === id) {
          return {
            ...userScore,
            value: userScore.value + delta
          };
        } else {
          return userScore;
        }
      })
    );
  };
```

This is just as simple, but if you want to add another action, the `useReducer` hook is better set up for it.

Comment: ok so I havent used useReducer before so it's still a bit confusing, but I think im getting your point. It seems neater as well.

Comment: You used .map over here coz we wanted to compare the ids. But I just searched useReducer and many have used switch case with it. Why's that? Can't we use switch case over here ?

Comment: I'll need more specifics than "over here" to help further. Switches on `useReducer` generally have to do with multiple "actions", originally I was going to write increment and decrement as two separate actions which is why I chose `useReducer`. I then realized that they could be coded as the same action.

I mapped over the elements because I didn't want to assume there'd always be 4. This could be more efficient with another object instead of an array, but then you'd have to do some more work to render it in order.